# Making it easier to copy webpage text to the clipboard (in iOS)?

Tags: safari, copy-paste

I have a web page that updates occasionally with new information (I made it myself - simple HTML page - nothing special).

I regularly have to copy this page to the clipboard on my iOS device to paste its contents into another iOS app. My current strategy is to make it a home screen icon, so I can:

1) Tap it to launch

2) Tap and hold on the text to begin selecting

3) Click 'select all'

4) Click 'copy'.

I am wondering if there are any HTML/JS tricks I can enact on the webpage side, or alternatively any apps/iOS tricks I can do on the client side, that would reduce the number of total clicks/steps involved (anything fewer than the four taps above would be a 'win' for me!). If it helps, I always want to copy the page in its entirety.

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272089/programmatically-selecting-text-in-an-input-field-on-ios-devices-mobile-safari) on Stack Overflow for pre-selecting text on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

This might be too simple an answer, but using an AppleScript or possibly Automator, or both to automate Safari should do the trick, and you could then use cron to schedule the task for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the answer - but I am trying to work with iOS (my apologies for the badly worded question, which only mentioned this in passing in one place - I've edited it to make it clearer!)

Comment: How about writing your own application that will use a UIWebView (think that’s what it’s called) to grab the contents of your website, & copy it to the clipboard for you. I’ve no idea if this is possible or not. I do know that you can install your own apps on your phone for testing purposes. I assume this would work well enough.